# How to extract multiple values from the same String with Regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape some data from a webpage. The data I need is within the `<meta>` tag of the html source. Scraping the data and saving it to a String with BeautifulSoup is no problem.

The String contains 2 numbers I want to extract. Each of those numbers (review scores from 1-100) should be assigned to a distinct variable for further processing.

```
test_str = "<meta content=\"Overall Rating: 79/100 ... Some Info ... Score: 86/100 \"/>"
```

The first value is `79/100` and the second is `86/100`, but I only need `79` and `86`. So far I have created a regex search to find those values and then `.replace("/100")` to clean things up.

But with my code, I only get the value for the first regex search match, which is `79`. I tried getting the second value with `m.group(1)` but it doesn't work.

What am I missing ?

```
test_str = "<meta content=\"Overall Rating: 79/100 ... Some Info ... Score: 86/100 \"/>"

m = re.search("../100", test_str)
if m:
    found = m.group(0).replace("/100","")
    print found

    # output -> 79
```

Thanks for your help.

Best regards!

Comment: `re.findall` return an array of matches

Comment: Are you scraping the web page and then take the entire HTML source and apply regex to it? I'm asking because your code sample shows no beautifulsoup-related code.

Comment: Thanks! @Tomalak No I just save the data in a String using  `meta_description = soup.find("meta", {"name": "rating-data"})`. I just didn't include the part of BeautifulSoup to keep things simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test_str = "<meta content=\"Overall Rating: 79/100 ... Some Info ... Score: 86/100 \"/>"    
m =  re.findall('(\d+(?=\/100))', test_str)
# m = ['79', '86']
```

I changed `..` with `/d+` so you can search for either 1 digit or 2

I also use a positive lookahead `(?=...)`, so the `.replace` becomes unnecessary

Example at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KveAbr/2)

Comment: Np glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know why most people are not suggesting back references to a named group.

You can do something like below, syntax might not be perfect.

```
test_str = "<meta content=\"Overall Rating: 79/100 ... Some Info ... Score: 86/100 \"/>"

pattern = "^<meta content=\"Overall Rating: (?P<rating>.*?) ... Some Info ... (?P<score>.*?)$"

match = re.match(pattern, test_str)

match.group('rating')
match.group('score')
```